# USB keyboard suddenly doesn't respond with MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, usb

So I got new a HP USB keyboard with my MacBook Pro. It worked fine for a couple of weeks. Now it suddenly stopped responding.

After a lot of research on the web, I already tried the following:

1. Use different USB ports
2. Use an extension cable
3. Use connect through a different device (extra USB port on laptop fan stand)
4. Restart computer
5. Reset PRAM
6. Reset SMC
7. Safe mode

I know the keyboard is fine, because it works on a different PC laptop.

I know the USB ports work with other devices.

What could be the problem, what other steps could I try?

Comment: Can you try another USB Keyboard?

Comment: Good idea, I haven't got one right now, but will soon.. If it worked, what would it prove?

Comment: It would prove that it’s not your Mac

Comment: Well, its not the keyboard either, cuz that works with other computers... so this particular combination of Mac + USB keyboard is kaput?

Comment: Don’t know, there could be some sort of incompatibility.  The other thing I would try is booting into Safe or Recovery mode to rule out your installed OS.

Comment: Safe mode I already tried... Lemme try recovery mode...